# External subwoofer not working Asus N76VM

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have installed the latest Ubuntu [14.04 LTS] on my Asus N76VM laptop.
The subwoofer was not working at all at this stage. I have followed the next steps:

1. Added in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` the code:

> options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4

2. Added in `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/extra-hdmi.conf` the code:

> [Mapping analog-surround-21]
>   device-strings = surround40:%f
>   channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe,lfe
>   paths-output = analog-output analog-output-speaker
>   priority = 7
>   direction = output

**Note:** tried writing the direction "out" instead of "output", but it does not work at all.

> direction = out

3. Enabled in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` :

> enable-lfe-remixing = yes

4. Reboot

> lspci | grep Audio

I have the following soundcard:

`Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)`

### Now if I pick in Sistem Settings > Sound > Analog Surround 2.1 Output, I have no sound at all.

Can anyone help me?
 Thank you in advance!